Can I live (non-carnally) with someone of the same sex?
Scripture... does not approve of homosexuality.
On the other hand, I know of no prohibition against loving (in a non-carnal manner!) and living with one's parents or siblings, and certainly many, many people spend years of their lives living with one or more thereof. In some cases, "siblings" might even be adopted. Historically, cohabitation of persons of the same sex is hardly unusual (schools, militaries, monasteries/nunneries).
This got me wondering... I can't offhand think of any scripture that forbids living in the same household with a person of the same sex, provided that one is not engaged in... inappropriate activities.
Does any denomination teach that this is forbidden, even among people that "love" (but not carnally!) one another? (Does Scripture?)

I've been in a fair few churches that would teach from the pulpit that it is not a good idea. They usually give two basic reasons: 1) it places you in a situation of undue temptation, 2) we are to avoid the appearance of evil. Obviously these two reasons bring a lot of assumptions in without addressing them.

@user80226, possibly, but particularly roommates that I "love" with the closeness of family. Or, for that matter, {house,room}mates that are family, e.g. adult siblings living together. Specifically, though, I am thinking about how to approach individuals engaged in homosexual cohabitation. Leaving aside Mike's (pertinent!) point about undue temptation, is it a problem that they care for each other (assuming they even have a deeper relationship), or is the problem "just" the inappropriate carnal activities?

More to the point, when such couple says "but we love each other; surely that can't be wrong!"... is mere (storge/filia, or even agape) love sinful in such instances, or is it "just" the eros that's the problem?

The answer to the question as stated seems a clear "yes", there's nothing wrong with having a roommate/housemate, in fact it's pretty common to save on rent (going all the way back to Sherlock Holmes). But in your case where apparently there have been inappropriate activities, the same arguments apply regarding avoiding temptation and avoiding the appearance of sin as would apply to heterosexual cohabitation.

@user111403, care to make that an Answer?

Is it forbidden to live in a household with another person of the same sex? Of course not. It's hard to prove a negative, but I'm not aware of a single denomination that would frown on this.
Your comments, though, suggest that there's more behind the question than just roommates or even close friendship. If there's anything approaching a romantic relationship, or an acknowledged homosexual attraction, or especially if there have been inappropriate activities in the past, then by simple logic all the arguments used against heterosexual cohabitation apply. Most notably, these are avoiding temptation:

2 Tim. 2:22 Flee also youthful lusts: but follow righteousness, faith, charity, peace, with them that call on the Lord out of a pure heart.

And avoiding the appearance of sin:

1 Thes. 5:22 Abstain from all appearance of evil.

This question seems relevant.

I can't prove that any denomination disapproves of this, but I have never heard of it. It would make college dorm life pretty difficult, as the assumption is usually that you'll have a same-sex roommate. Throughout history and in the present day, it is common for singles of the same sex to cohabit, as a way to mitigate loneliness and reduce housing costs.
In fact, many Christian denominations actively encourage single people of the same sex to live together, as you already mention monastic practices. In fact, in historical Eastern Orthodox practice, they had a church-sanctioned official ritual called adelphopoiesis by which two men would become essentially brothers and be expected to live together and support one another. Of course, many modern people would look at this practice and see some homosexual overtones, but that was certainly not the intention of the practice.
